# Refusing to connect: Ruby on Rails not connecting to any ports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, server, ruby-on-rails-5

My OS: Windows 10
Shell: Ubuntu (from the Microsoft Store)
Rails: 5.0.6
Ruby: 2.4.2

I installed Ruby on Rails using the Ubuntu Shell for Windows. After installing Ruby on Rails, I created a new project (testapp), and I am trying to connect to localhost:3000.

After a lot of searching, checking my /etc/hosts, checking my host file on windows, uninstalling eset, uninstalling XAMPP, Ruby on Rails still refuses to connect to localhost:3000.

I tried to bind it to a different port (multiple times), for example I tried to change it to port 3001, or port 4000, and it still wouldn't work. I tried rails s -b 0.0.0.0, this still doesn't work. I also tried 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.1:3000, etc.

In the image, I am just showing that I tried rails s to connect to localhost:3000.

Can anybody please help me on why this isn't working? I am confused.

[me trying to connect rails to port 3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1cV6.png)

[Ruby and Rails Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwlpw.png)

Comment: Sometimes "multiple processes" all bind to port 3000, try rebooting and see if it works then? :)

Comment: It's not just port 3000. It's every port.

Comment: Have you gone through these? https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1498

Comment: Why do you think that Rails did not listen on port 3000? Looking at your screenshot it feels to me like the server started without any errors and was ready to return requests on port 3000 until you stopped the server with `CTRL+C`.

Comment: If you open a second bash prompt and do `curl http://localhost:3000` does it work?

Comment: @rogerdpack: No, I get the message 'failed to connect, connection refused'

Comment: You may have more luck with an Ubuntu VM (ex: virtualbox).  It "should" work.  Or possibly try with a simple webrick server, see if that works.

Comment: Update to everybody: I just installed Ubuntu on Virtualbox. It works. I'm still not sure why it is working on Windows. Thanks for helping everybody!